# Deserializing a JSON into a record causes JSON parse error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, java-17

I have a method in a rest controller that takes a JSON request body and should deserialize it into a record called TransactionDTO, but it keeps giving me the error: `Could not resolve parameter [0] in private org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.web.store.app.backend.dto.TransactionDTO> com.web.store.app.backend.controller.TransactionController.saveTransaction(com.web.store.app.backend.dto.TransactionDTO): JSON parse error: Can not set final java.util.List field com.web.store.app.backend.dto.TransactionDTO.productIds to java.util.ArrayList`

I know that the problem is because I am using a record. When I change it to a class and remove the final from the parameters it works, but I want to avoid using a class as a DTO if possible.

the method:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "add")
    private ResponseEntity<TransactionDTO> saveTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody TransactionDTO transactionDTO) {

        return transactionService.saveTransaction(transactionDTO).map(
                transaction -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(transaction)).orElseGet(
                () -> ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .build());
    }
```

TransactionDTO:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public record TransactionDTO(String id, Long userId,
                             @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
                             ZonedDateTime createdAt, List<String> productIds) {}
```

The request used:

`curl --location 'localhost:8080/transaction/api/add' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{     "id": "TRNS03",     "user_id": 1,     "created_at":"2023-03-19T06:33-06:00",     "product_ids":["PRD003"] }'`

Comment: Can't test right now, but if I remember correctly you need to use `@JsonProperty` on every parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Which version of Jackson are you using? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2709

Comment: Adding `@JsonProperty` fixed it for me. Strange how it works without it in 2 other dtos I have, but it doesn't on this one. thanks, @chaosfire